# What is my Instagram password if I created it with my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, instagram

I need my password for my Instagram to connect it to my business Facebook page but I created it with my regular Facebook so I don't have a password.

Answer (score 2):

By default it will be your Facebook password. To get separate password you have to create new one for Instagram.

First login to your Instagram account as you login regular with Facebook.

Go to your Instagram profile and click on [Edit Profile](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/).

Enter the **Email** address you wish to use for login (if there is no email address associated with the account, and make sure you have access of this email), set a **Username** (if you have not set any, you can use your username instead of email id with password to login your account).

Now go to https://www.instagram.com and tap **Forgot?** next to Password on the log in screen to [reset your password](https://help.instagram.com/374546259294234/):

> - To reset through your email address, tap **Username or Email**, enter your username or the email address you used to create your account and tap search. Choose **Send a Password Reset Email**.
> - To reset through Facebook, tap **Reset using Facebook**. You may be asked to log into Facebook. You can then enter a new password for the Instagram account that was most recently linked to your Facebook account.
>
> Note: If you can't access the email you registered with and you didn't link your Instagram account to Facebook, we're not able to give you access to this account.

After resetting your password you can [unlink](https://help.instagram.com/536741816349927) your Facebook account from Instagram first and then you can connect it with other Facebook account or Page.